# Add details to your own answer which are unrelated to question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

I have given [an answer to the question "String immutable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841209/string-immutable/29841304#29841304), in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, which is one of my most highly upvoted and accepted answers.

In that question OP asked only about string immutability, which I have explained.

Now what I want to do is to add more details in that answer, for example string comparison with equals and ==, which is different from what the user asked.

Why do I want to do that? I keep on forgetting about the concepts of `String`. I tried making some notes, but they are lost somehow, so I want to keep all these related concepts in one place so that I can find them easily. It would also be helpful for others.

I will understand those concepts, and explain in the best possible way so that after some time, when I have some confusion I can come to that answer and refresh my memory.

I just want to know if it is a good practice to post unrelated details in a answer?

I am confused between if I post more details it would be helpful for me and I think to other also but on the other hand If this would be allowed(or good practice) by SO or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't a very good idea. Putting unrelated details into your answer means that searchers and other people, who are *just* looking for information about string immutability, have to read through those details. That's going to be a waste of their time, at best. (It might even annoy some of them enough to cast a downvote.)

A better idea, if you have important, useful information you want to share, would be to [post your own Q&A pair on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132887/). You can write a question about whatever you like* and answer it yourself to share your knowledge, or make it easy for you to find again.

Just take care [to post a really *good* question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180845/); your fellow users are going to judge it like any other.

---

*As long as it's on topic for the site.

Comment: Well, posting a few little additional tidbits would be fine.  In this case the additional info would just be too much to include in the answer without detracting from the existing content.

Comment: That's true, @Servy; there is some question of degree.

Comment: my answer is accepted so I can say that user got the answer so after that I can mention in heading that unrellated to question then post some details(so other searcing would not be misguided) . would that be good? .And also the concept which I want to ask are related to some of the question  but no with answer(explanation) of them so if I post a new question with that It would be marked a duplicate and downvoted thats why I am not postng new question?

Comment: I suppose if the question is about a concept, then going beyond the bounds of the concept doesn't make much sense. But are those mostly questions you see? It is common with what I answer on that the question itself is only tangential to the problem with the code. Yes, you could answer the question directly with a one-liner, or a paragraph, but it won't really help the OP or a searcher to just patch together a "working" program and move on.

Comment: @singhakash I think it's generally not a good idea to include **unrelated** details in an answer. Including some **related** details that go beyond the immediate scope of the question, but that you believe would be useful for somebody reading the answer, can be perfectly fine.